# Want to route one component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to `ReactJS` I have Three components `App.js` ,`Login.js`,`Register.js` when the wepapp is launched it first launched `App.js` in that component i have two buttons "Login" and "Register" ,By clicking on Login button it should goto the `LogIn` component and on click on Register button it should goto `Register` component,I am not finding a clean way to achieve that.
Here is my code for `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.gotoLogin = this.gotoLogin.bind(this);
    this.gotoRegister = this.gotoRegister.bind(this);

  }

  gotoLogin() {


    alert("Login");
  }

   gotoRegister() {

      alert("Register");

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <button  onClick={this.gotoLogin} class="Button ">Login</button>
        <button  onClick ={this.gotoRegister} class="Button">Register</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

code for `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Respective i have also component class for `Login.js and Register.js`

Comment: If you see i have bind it in top inside constructor  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.gotoLogin = this.gotoLogin.bind(this);
    this.gotoRegister = this.gotoRegister.bind(this);

  }

Comment: Are you using any routing library?

Comment: react-router i can use but not sure how to proceed with that

Comment: There is documentation which pretty much explains everything on the repo. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs.

Comment: Which version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: can share you router part ?

Comment: Please share @MayankShukla

Comment: @DroidNoob its v4.0.0

Comment: They have released another package just for the web `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your efforts `@Mayank @Johib @hod caspi and @sneha` i found the root cause of the issue .I was using `react-router 4.0.0` which has an internal implementation error it doesn't find the `location` then i had to downgrade the `react-router to 3.0.3` then again another error not undefined getCurrentlocation and i had to pass `<Router history={browserHistory}>`  the `history` like this.Here is my final code looks like

> App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


import { Link, Router, RouterContext, browserHistory, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.gotoLogin = this.gotoLogin.bind(this);
    this.gotoRegister = this.gotoRegister.bind(this);
  }



  gotoLogin() {

    browserHistory.push("/login");
  }

  gotoRegister() {
    browserHistory.push("/register");

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>

        <button onClick={this.gotoLogin} >Login</button>
        <button onClick={this.gotoRegister} >Register</button>
        <Link to={'/login'} >Login</Link>
        {this.props.children}

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

> index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Login from './Login';
import Register from './Register';

import './index.css';
import {Route, Router,browserHistory } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render( 
<Router history={browserHistory}> 

<Route path="/" component={App} /> 
<Route path="/login" component={Login} /> 
<Route path="/register" component={Register} /> 

</Router>, 
document.getElementById('root') 
)
```

Comment: Great to hear, if you like my answer and effort you can vote

Answer (score 1):

If you using `router v2 or v3`, use this:

```
gotoLogin() {
   hashHistory.push("/Login");  or browserHistory.push("/Login");
}

gotoRegister() {
    hashHistory.push("/Register");  or browserHistory.push("/Register");
}
```

**Note**: Use the same `history` that you are using with `react-router`.

If you are using `router v4`, use this:

```
gotoLogin() {
   this.context.router.transitionTo("/Login"); 
}

gotoRegister() {
    this.context.router.transitionTo("/Register"); 
}
```

**Note**: You need to define the `contextTypes` with you component.

Check this example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super();
    const { router } = this.context;
  }
  ....
}

App.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Now use this: `router.transitionTo("/Login");`

Check this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4129

Comment: This import is import { Router, Route, Link,browserHistory } from 'react-router' correct for this?

Comment: Giving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined I have the recent version so i used  this.context.router.transitionTo("/Login");  its giving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined

Comment: check your package.json

Comment: check your package.json file or show how you define the routes.

Comment: {
  "name": "admin-addxlushive",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}

Comment: you are using  "react-router": "^4.0.0"

Comment: check the updated answer, you need to define the `contextTypes` like i defined in example. Define in a similar way then you can directly use `this.context.router.transitionTo("/Register");` or u can save `this.context.router` in a seperate variable and use `router.transitionTo`.

Comment: now getting this error  22:5   error    'router' is not defined                      no-undef
 26:4   error    'router' is not defined                      no-undef

Comment: check this i think you are doing some other mistake: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4129

Comment: Can you show how you are rendering this component ? You are rendering your Component inside of one of the router components ??

Comment: All the components are different js files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139574/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-abhijit-chakra).

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
    </div>
    <button href='#/login' onClick={this.gotoLogin} class="Button ">Login</button>
    <button href='#/register' onClick ={this.gotoRegister} class="Button">Register</button>
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: href i dont want to use i want to use react router

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Link component import from 'react-router', then you should write something like this:

```
import { Link, Router, RouterContext, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
```

// inside the component inser the component:

```
                        <Link to={'/login'}>clikc to login</Link>
```

so the button should be like this:

```
  <Link to={'/login'} class="Button ">Login</Link>
```

if it help you please vote
Thanks Hod

Comment: He is using v4. There is `browserHistory` in v4

Comment: you right, with that he can do it directly without create a function that will transfer the page

Comment: @hodcaspi i want to Route when the button is clicked how can i put this code in above code

Comment: this: <button  onClick={this.gotoLogin} class="Button ">Login</button>
should be:  <Link to={'/login'} class="Button ">Login</Link>

Comment: please vote the answer is useful if you find it helpfull @AbhijitChakra

Comment: Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App` this error

Comment: did you import Link from react-router ?? please follow the answer again

Comment: import { Link, Router, RouterContext, browserHistory } from 'react-router';  i did

Comment: you have written {'/login'} buit my component name is Login ..Is the above code need modification

Comment: what you enter inside the to at the  Link component, should be exactly the route in your main route js

Comment: to={} , mean the place you page will go

Comment: do you have route config file??

Comment: I dont have any rout config file

Comment: check it out : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';


<ul>
      <li><Link to="/login" onClick={this.gotoLogin}>Login</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/register" onClick ={this.gotoRegister}>Register</Link></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I Want inside button